# Phoenix Error while trying to create table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

When I either log in to sqlline.py in phoenix or I try to create table in phoenix through api's I get  an exception.

With my limited knowledge of phenix I am unable to figure out why phoenix is checking for System.Catalog table even before it creates it.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

StackTrace:

*4/11/18 06:07:18 WARN client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Encountered problems when prefetch META table:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: Cannot find row in .META. for table: SYSTEM.CATALOG, row=SYSTEM.CATALOG,\x00SYSTEM\x00CATALOG,99999999999999
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.prefetchRegionCache(HConnectionManager.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:958)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:914)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1053)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1156)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:422)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:183)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:226)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:908)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1351)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:131)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:112)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$DatabaseConnection.connect(SqlLine.java:4650)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$DatabaseConnection.getConnection(SqlLine.java:4701)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$Commands.connect(SqlLine.java:3942)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$Commands.connect(SqlLine.java:3851)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(SqlLine.java:2810)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:817)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:633)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:680)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.mainWithInputRedirection(SqlLine.java:441)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:424)
Error: SYSTEM.CATALOG (state=08000,code=101)
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:97)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:935)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1053)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1156)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:422)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:183)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:226)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:908)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1351)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:131)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:112)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$DatabaseConnection.connect(SqlLine.java:4650)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$DatabaseConnection.getConnection(SqlLine.java:4701)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$Commands.connect(SqlLine.java:3942)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$Commands.connect(SqlLine.java:3851)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(SqlLine.java:2810)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:817)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:633)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:680)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.mainWithInputRedirection(SqlLine.java:441)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:424)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: SYSTEM.CATALOG
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:958)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:914)
    ... 23 more*
```

Comment: Have you even created the table? do "show tables" to check

Comment: It is also possible that your hbase master and slave haven't started

Comment: hmaster and region servers are running;I can create a table from hbase.The problem is with phoenix;it cannot establish a connection to hbase.

Comment: Is it a remote connection?

Comment: I just setup phoenix from scratch with hbase on hadoop as have not encountered any errors. Are you using standalone or pseudo distributed hbase?

Answer (score 0):

Check your hdfs://.../hbase/data/default/ is exist SYSTEM.CATALOG ? 
[image]

if there is nothing, you must try to use bin/hbase clean --cleanZk
before you use the command, you must stop hbase Master and regionServers,but still keep ZK alive.